# Pester version 5 pass variables to test

Tags: powershell, pester

I'm stuck on how to pass parameters to my Pester v5 tests.

This is my config-file in Pester:

```
Import-Module Pester -Force
$testFile = 'C:\PowerShell\MyTests\'

$tr = 'C:\PowerShell\MyTests\TEST-MyTests.xml'

$configuration = [PesterConfiguration]@{
  PassThru = $true
  Run = @{
     Path = $testFile
  }
  Output = @{
     Verbosity = 'Detailed'
  }

  TestResult = @{
     Enabled = $true
     OutputFormat = "NUnitXml"
     OutputPath   = $tr
  }
}       

Invoke-Pester -Configuration $configuration
```

This is my simple test where I need to pass value to variable testUrl, this value is now hard coded:

```
BeforeAll {
    $tesUrl = "https://test.com/"

}
Describe "Status of my testsystem" {
    It "Should be http code 200" {
        $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($tesUrl)
        $request.Method = "HEAD"
        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        $response.StatusCode | Should -Be 200
    }
}
```

How can i pass parameters in to the Pester-test so I can run the test for several environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation here: https://pester.dev/docs/usage/data-driven-tests#providing-external-data-to-tests

You need to use `New-PesterContainer` to create an object with the test data you want to use, and then add that to your Pester configuration object under `Run.Container` :

```
Import-Module Pester -Force
$testFile = 'C:\PowerShell\MyTests\'

$tr = 'C:\PowerShell\MyTests\TEST-MyTests.xml'

$Container = New-PesterContainer -Path $testFile -Data @{ 
   testurl  = 'https://urlyouwanttotest.com/'
}

$configuration = [PesterConfiguration]@{
  Run = @{
   PassThru = $true
   Container = $Container
  }
  Output = @{
     Verbosity = 'Detailed'
  }

  TestResult = @{
     Enabled = $true
     OutputFormat = "NUnitXml"
     OutputPath   = $tr
     }
  }       

  Invoke-Pester -Configuration $configuration
```

Your test file then needs to include a `param` block:

```
param(
   [string]
   $testurl
)

BeforeAll {
    $tesUrl = $testUrl
}

Describe "Status of my testsystem" {
    It "Should be http code 200" {
        $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($tesUrl)
        $request.Method = "HEAD"
        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        $response.StatusCode | Should -Be 200
    }
}
```